# Populate SelectListItem from generic data type

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, selectlistitem

I have the following code which returns results from a database table comprising of an Id field and a Name field, and transfers it to a list of SelectListItems (this populates a dropdown box in my view.)

```
var locationTypes = await APIHelper.GetAsync<List<LocationType>>(url);

var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

items.AddRange(locationTypes.Select(locationType =>
{
    var item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Value = locationType.LocationTypeId.ToString();
    item.Text = locationType.Name;
    return item;
}));
```

I am repeating this a lot throughout my application, substituting LocationType for various other things. The item.Value always gets the Id property of the data returned (the Id field is always in the format of {TableName}+"Id"), and the item.Text always gets ".Name" property.

How can I make this generic? I am trying to achieve something like this, although it is syntactically incorrect and may be the incorrect approach:

```
var myGenericObjects = await APIHelper.GetAsync<List<T>>(url)

var items = new List<SelectListItem>();

items.AddRange(myGenericObjects .Select(myGenericObjects =>
{
    var item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Value = myGenericObject.Field[0].ToString();
    item.Text = myGenericObject.Name;
    return item;
}));
```

Comment: Try ```var data = locationTypes.ToDictionary(lt => lt.LocationTypeId, lt => lt.Name)``` and then use ```new SelectList(data, "Key", "Value")```.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkG - but how can I do lt => lt[0] (i.e. the first field) rather than specify LocationTypeId

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom extension for a generic list object, then, using reflection retrieve the values that you are wanting to map to the SelectListItem.Text and Name fields. Note I am using "nameof" in order to prevent any confusion or magic string representations of the properties to which I am trying to map.

I did define a default value of "Name" to the namePropertyName parameter. Per your description it sounded like, by convention, most of your DTOs have the property "Name" in them. If that's not the case simply remove the default value that is defined.

There are additional checks that could be made to this extension to prevent NullReference and ArgumentExceptions as well, but for simplicity of the example were left out. Example: Ensuring a value is provided in the idPropertyName and namePropertyName parameters and ensuring those property names exist on the provided generic object prior to conversion.

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<SelectListItem> ToSelectList<T>(this List<T> list, string idPropertyName, string namePropertyName = "Name")
        where T : class, new()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> selectListItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

        list.ForEach(item =>
        {
            selectListItems.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item.GetType().GetProperty(namePropertyName).GetValue(item).ToString(),
                Value = item.GetType().GetProperty(idPropertyName).GetValue(item).ToString()
            });
        });

        return selectListItems;
    }
}
```

Example Use:

```
var testList = new List<TestDto>
{
    new TestDto { Name = "Test0", TestId = 0 },
    new TestDto { Name = "Test1", TestId = 1 },
    new TestDto { Name = "Test2", TestId = 2 },
    new TestDto { Name = "Test3", TestId = 3 },
    new TestDto { Name = "Test4", TestId = 4 },
};

var selectList = testList.ToSelectList(nameof(TestDto.TestId), nameof(TestDto.Name));
```

Here is the TestDto class for reference:

```
public class TestDto
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This was incredibly helpful, thank you kind sir! Note in the `.Add( ... ` I changed Text to get name, and Value to get id, rather than vice versa :)

Comment: Ya... caught that after I posted... didn’t have enough rep point to correct it :-D  I’m glad I could help!

Comment: No problem, impressive start to StackOverflow!  I noticed the code works without `where T : class, new()` - what is its purpose?

Comment: Those are type constraints. “class” restricts “T” to C# class types and “new()” says that the provided class has to have an empty constructor defined. Since most Dtos are simple POCO classes it was a safe bet to add these constraints. You don’t want someone to try to convert a List<string> or List<Enum> when you know the types you are trying to convert are classes and have empty constructors

Comment: In other words... removing the type constraints would allow you to pass in any List<T> object and is why removing them works for you, but opens the door for someone else to accidentally misuse the extension method for non conforming objects.

Comment: Does this help with performance or purely to try and give some kind of inbuilt documentation to the method? Surely if anyone tries such madness they'll soon see all the errors saying.. no it doesn't work like this :) - excuse me trying to make real world sense of the c# beast

Comment: @egmfrs If someone tries such madness they will only see the errors at runtime. This gives compile time support and the compiler will stop them.

Comment: @CodingYoshi is right, and is why you try to constrain the use through type constraints and/or adding additional checks within the method. Reflection can be a bit of magic that people don’t often like to have on their code, however, if understood and properly used it is a very powerful feature of the .Net Framework

Comment: @egmfrs Type constraints are only there to restrict the available types to the ones you want to allow for the method. The performance gains by removing he constraints are minuscule in this case, and the benefit of restricting the method from misuse far outweighs the millisecond in performance you might lose IMHO

Answer (score 0):

**Some Prep Work**

If you can change the table column names, then use a convention. For example, always name the "Value" column "X", and the "Text" column "Y" (give them better names). Then make all the classes for those tables implement an interface similar to this:

```
public interface ICustomLookup
{
    string X { get; set; }
    string Y { get; set; }
}

public class SomeClass : ICustomLookup
{
    public string X { get; set; }
    public string Y { get; set; }
}
```

Then an extension method like so:

```
public static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static SelectList ToSelectList(this IEnumerable<ICustomLookup> items)
    {
        return new SelectList(items.Select(thisItem => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = thisItem.X,
            Value = thisItem.Y
        }));
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var items = new List<SomeClass>
{
    new SomeClass { X = "XOne", Y = "YOne" },
    new SomeClass { X = "XTwo", Y = "YTwo" }
};
SelectList selectList = items.ToSelectList();
```

Comment: If I could change my column names I would just rename all Id's to "Id" and then my proposed code would be OK if I just used myGenericObject.Id instead of `myGenericObject.Field[0]` which was the bit I struggled with. In any case, thanks for your time and the lesson at least.

Comment: @egmfrs Sure no worries. When you said you have this everywhere in your project, I figured you could use this convention because it will help the readability and understandability of code and the project. I also wanted to avoid reflection (I lean towards reflection as a last resort). I have used this technique numerous times and it has several other benefits too.

Comment: Thanks - Is it possible to add an interface with int id, and then inherit this in my classes and set id => MytableId ? Or is that crazy talk. Also what is the reason to avoid reflection?

Comment: @egmfrs The table column name has to be the same as the interface. Then your class for the table will automatically be satisfying the interface. If they are different, then in the interface implementation you can return the value of the mapping column. Reflection is slow (slower than this approach) and your project will not have a consistent design. With this approach, you, other devs, users of your API (if any) will get used to your design with much ease.